# SQL Server, subset a table and create new column based on condition

Tags: sql-server, subset

If I have a table in SQL as:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |

What I need to do, logically is:

1. Get the top row of each group when grouped by id, ordered by code
2. Create a new column to show if the code column contained a 7 anywhere, within the group

Desired result:

| id | code | c7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | N |
| 2 | 3 | Y |
| 3 | 6 | Y |

I think it needs a "CASE WHEN" statement in the SELECT, but have not worked it out. What query can I execute to get this?

Comment: What defines the "top" row? I don't see anything that denotes what the "top" row is. It;s not the `MAX` values, and there's nothing in your table to order your data to determine a "first" row.

Comment: @Larnu Good question ... sorry. Doesn't really matter but lets say ordered by code? but obviously result will look slightly different ...

Comment: Then should `id` `3` not have the value `6` for `code` in your expected results?

Comment: @Larnu, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you can use a `MIN` and a conditional aggregate:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MIN(Code) AS Code,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE code WHEN 7 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS C7
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do this, but what comes to mind is that first you have to partition the table to get the top one based on whatever that criteria is, then join back against itself to find the ones with the 7

```sql
declare @table1 table (id int not null, code int not null)

insert into @table1 (id, code)
values
(1,6),
(1,8),
(1,4),
(2,3),
(2,7),
(2,4),
(3,7),
(3,6),
(3,7)

select id, code, c7
from (
    select t.id ,t.code
        ,(CASE WHEN c.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' END) as c7
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id order by t.code) AS p 
    from @table1 t
        left outer join (
            select id, code, 'Y' as c7
            from @table1
            where code = 7) c on c.id = t.id
    ) sorted
where sorted.p = 1
```